# Difference between portable, mobile, handheld and wearable devices

Tags: nouns

What are main differences in portable, mobile, handheld and wearable devices in technical area and what are some examples of devices from each category?

Comment: Have you checked their respective dictionary definitions?

Comment: I did found that mobile and portable are in fact synonyms but other than that nothing helpful :/

Comment: I don't really see how this is strictly applicable to English. It seems more suited to a technology site. As soon as you add *device* to one of the words, it ends up being something that may have a different meaning than just the word on its own. If you were to ask what the difference was between each of the single words, that would have some bearing here—but you would still need to provide dictionary definitions in your question in order for it to show sufficient research. But asking about **devices** specifically doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 2):

There is overlap between the terms when talking about devices

[Portable](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/portable?s=t) - *capable of being [easily] transported or conveyed*. E.g. a laptop computer is a portable device (compared to a desktop device which can be moved only with some difficulty).

[Mobile](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mobile?s=t) - *capable of moving or being moved readily.* Essentially a subset of portable, especially when designed to be used on the move, e.g. mobile/cell phones.

[Handheld](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/handheld?s=t) - *small enough to be used or operated while being held in the hand or hands*. E.g. mobile/cell phones or tablet computers.

[Wearable](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wearable?s=t) - *relating to or noting a computer or advanced electronic device that is incorporated into an accessory worn on the body or an item of clothing.* E.g. smart watches.

So mobile devices are a subset of portable devices while handheld and wearable devices are subsets of mobile devices.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot for description.